# Racket GUI: how to get rid of Emacs keybindings with framework:text%

Tags: racket

Using the Racket GUI framework, I found that the defaults keybindings of the text editor are the same as Emacs. That is said: completely unreasonable for most of applications. In order to activate the contextual menu Copy/Cut/Paste, I use `racket:text%` from framework.
`Control + A` don't select all the text, but move the caret to the beginning of the line.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/framework/Keymap.html

How to get rid of this craziness and map `"Ctrl + A"` to `"Select All"`?

Edit: I was asked for an example, it can be copy/pasted into DrRacket

```
#lang racket/gui

(require framework)

(define main-frame (new frame%
                        [label  "Test Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E"]
                        [width  640]
                        [height 280]))

(define log-text (new editor-canvas%
                      [label  #f]
                      [vert-margin 10]
                      [parent main-frame]))

;; rich text editor
(define text-editor (new racket:text%))

(send log-text set-editor text-editor)
(send text-editor insert (format "Test Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E here"))

(send main-frame show #t)
```

Edit: in DrRacket `Ctrl+A` select all the text, as expected.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code you have so far?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, that was surprisingly annoying to suss out. Hopefully that helps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket's GUI editors have a keymap which can be set with `set-keymap`. A editor with a keymap with `Ctr+A` bound to select all can be found in `keymap:get-editor`. So if you add the line:

```
(send text-editor set-keymap (keymap:get-editor))
```

to your code it should change the key bindings from `Ctr+A` going to the beginning of the line, to highlighting everything.

```
#lang racket/gui

(require framework)

(define main-frame (new frame%
                        [label  "Test Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E"]
                        [width  640]
                        [height 280]))

(define log-text (new editor-canvas%
                      [label  #f]
                      [vert-margin 10]
                      [parent main-frame]))

;; rich text editor
(define text-editor (new racket:text%))
(send text-editor set-keymap (keymap:get-editor))

(send log-text set-editor text-editor)
(send text-editor insert (format "Test Ctrl+A and Ctrl+E here"))

(send main-frame show #t)
```

Comment: Strange: with that small code change, we actually lose the contextual menu Copy/Paste/Select All.